# How to parse through a Node and extract the value of a child node in Java?

Tags: java, xpath

The input to the function this code is in, is a Node configNode. I need to extract the value of a child node inTemplate. The following is the code. Only null is printed.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Node inTemplateNode = (Node) xpath.compile("@inTemplate").evaluate(configNode, XPathConstants.NODE);
String inTemplate = (inTemplateNode != null) ? inTemplateNode.getTextContent() : null;
        System.out.println("inTemplate Value =" + inTemplate);
```

Can anyone help me as to why this code is not working.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also post the XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression `@inTemplate` selects the attribute named `inTemplate` of the context node (e.g. `<config inTemplate="foo"/>`). If you really need an attribute value then doing `((Element)configNode).getAttribute("inTemplate")` should work in the DOM without the need to use any XPath.

If you want to select a child element (e.g. `<config><inTemplate>foo</inTemplate></config>`) named `inTemplate` then use the path `inTemplate` and not `@inTemplate`.